# Visualization tool for a timeline using bars

Tags: javascript, visualization, timeline

I have a dataset consisting of event start in date and time format, event end in date and time format and the duration between the event 1 and event 2.

I can't include a picture since I do not have enough reputations. Therefore, I'm including a link instead: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9dCc.png

I have about 30 events which I want to display something like this:
http://i.imgur.com/ehCv8by.png

Now I'm wondering whether there is a tool for this visualization already or whether I should choose a different type of visualization for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Google chart lib: 
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

They provide a extra Timeline graph visualization.

Comment: Is there a way to use a slider for timeline graph visualization? Putting in 30 of my events makes each bar looks super tiny and it doesn't scale right

Comment: afaik there is no way provided by google, but you can use `overflow-x: scroll;` css to style the graph container and configure via options. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fcvcr3Lj/)

Comment: thank you! can you also use a date range picker for that purpose? like this example for google charts? http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex1

Comment: I changed the format to YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS so that it would fit the format which daterangepicker is using (https://jsfiddle.net/2jd8tL35/) but I can't think of a way to implement the rangepicker into the timeline graph visualization

Comment: I think it could be implemeneted but the effort is way to high because you need to repaint the graph each time you change the date. If you want to do so you need to create a "global" list of all events in JS and each time you change the date you need to filter this list and draw the filtered values.

Comment: With [this snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/mys08r4d/9/) you can start and improve it to adapt to your needs. It has some issues but I think you will get the idea.

Comment: thank you sir. I played around with it and tried to include the predefined rangepicker. My input in the HTML doesn't look right. I wanted to replace the old daterangepicker completely. Now it stopped working (https://jsfiddle.net/srk8938n/).

Comment: I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srk8938n/1/). The problem were multiple syntax errors because of missing brackets. If you need more help you can join me at [gitter.im](https://gitter.im/Wachiwi/helpdesk?utm_source=share-link&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=share-link) because comments are not meant for long discussions ;)